# Truecrypt & apache, how to manage the file permission?

Tags: apache-2.2, permissions, file-permissions, truecrypt

I'm on Ubuntu.
I use a truecrypt container to store all my working files.
My apache server run with the user `www-data` ( the default setting ).

When I mount the container using truecrypt, all my file are owned by fmaz:fmaz.
So when my PHP code try to do a chmod(), it fail -- permission denied.

So I've tried to mount the truecrypt volume like so:

```
truecrypt --auto-mount=devices --fs-options="uid=33,gid=1000"
```

as well as:

```
truecrypt --auto-mount=devices --fs-options="uid=1000,gid=33"
```

When doing a `ls -la` on the folder, I can see that the owning is valid ( www-data:fmaz or fmaz:www-data ) But the group doesn't seem to be taken into account.

**fmaz:www-data**
I can access my file, but apache/php can't work with them.

**www-data:fmaz**
Apache and PHP are happy, everything work fine, but I cannot access to my own files:

```
fmaz@fmaz-laptop:/$ cd media/truecrypt1/
bash: cd: media/truecrypt1/: Permission non accordée
```

But as you can see:

```
sudo ls -la media/truecrypt1/
total 31448
drwx------ 14 www-data fmaz     8192 1969-12-31 19:00 .
drwxr-xr-x  5 root     root     4096 2011-12-03 11:10 ..
-rwx------  1 www-data fmaz  3353256 2009-11-18 21:19 7nuj21us.exe
...
```

How can I configure the setup to be able to have full access to the file for Apache as well as myself ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `chown` the files/folders to `fmaz:www-data`.

Then, you need to add the read permission to group using `chmod g+r` (files) and `chmod g+rx` (folders).

If your PHP code requires modifying some directory/filer, you need to use `chmod g+wr`.

This is just one way of doing it.

Comment: Truecrypt seems to mount the container with fixed ownership. I can't chown the file once the container is mounted. Hoverwer, you're right, I just notice that my group didn't have any rights ! So the solution reside in your second sentence :p Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Solved this problem adding needed umask. 
I use truecrypt 7.1 with gui, so i went

settings->preferences->mount options

uid=www-data,gid=user,umask=007

it mounts volume with drwx-rwx----

just what i needed for my apache running inside truecrypt